# How many gigs is the AT launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am thinking of getting the ATLauncher to get modpacks, but i am limited to 2.5 gigabytes a day.

Can anyone tell me if I will be able to get it?
Or how many gigs it is anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launcher is about 1.5 *mega*bytes. So negligible.

Actual modpacks are the things that take up space, but usually less than 100-200 megabytes for a modpack. Unfortunately there is no way to see how large a modpack is prior to installing